# Show that $f(x)=x$ is Riemann integrable for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

What I have so far: We are assuming that $\alpha$ is a nondecreasing function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $a<b$. For $P\in \mathscr{P}([a,b]),$

$$U(P,f,\alpha) - L(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^{N}(x_k-x_{k-1})(\alpha(x_k)-\alpha(x_{k-1})).$$

We wish to show that $f\in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$, i.e. that for all $\epsilon_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ there exists a $P_{0}\in \mathscr{P}([a,b])$ for which
$$U(P_{0},f,\alpha) - L(P_{0},f,\alpha) < \epsilon_{0}.$$

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really meant to ask was about the Riemann-Stieltjes integrability of $f$. You should probably modify your title to reflect that. But anyways, that's just a minor point.

Here's the idea. So, if $x_k-x_{k-1}$ just happens to satisfy, say, $x_k-x_{k-1} < \epsilon_0$ for every $k$, then:
$$\sum_{k} (x_k-x_{k-1})(\alpha(x_k)-\alpha(x_{k-1})) < \epsilon_0 \sum_{k} (\alpha(x_k)-\alpha(x_{k-1})) = \epsilon_0 (\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))$$

But now, we just need to choose a partition $P$ such that $\left|\left|P \right|\right| \leq \frac{\epsilon_0}{2(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))+2}$. This ensures that $x_k-x_{k-1} \leq \left|\left|P\right|\right|$ for all $k$ and it ensures that your sum above satisfies the required inequality. I'm leaving out some of the details for you to check on your own but do ask about them if you are still confused :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I appreciate the help, but I'm confused. Are you saying that $x_k - x_{k-1} < \epsilon_{0}$? That is, that that difference is less than every epsilon? If that's what you're saying, then I don't see it.

Comment: No. In the first part of the derivation, I was just doing a bit of a heuristic argument where I assumed that $x_k-x_{k-1} < \epsilon_0$ and then proceeded to derive a consequence of that. Once I derived a consequence of that, it ended up being close to what we wanted. Then, I proceeded to specifically choose a partition where the norm of the partition (the maximum length of the subintervals [x_{k-1},x_k]) would be the quantity I specified above. This allows you to prove that $U(P_0,f,\alpha)-L(P_0,f,\alpha) \leq \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} < \epsilon_0$.

Comment: Hmm I don't think it is at all. You should really try to think about what I've said for a bit and try to explicitly write down some of the steps which I've skipped. It isn't always super clear in the beginning but it only gets more clear if you think about it more.

Comment: "Choose a $P_{0} \in \mathscr{P}([a,b])$ so that for $\epsilon_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{+},$ $U(P_{0},f,\alpha) - L(P_{0},f,\alpha) < \epsilon_{0}(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))$." I'm on the right track?

Comment: Yes you are. So, you could choose to just end the proof there, because $\epsilon_0$ is arbitrary and placing a constant in front of it won't matter so much. The only slight technicality there is that since $\alpha$ is non-decreasing, we could still have that $\alpha(b)=\alpha(a)$ and the right-hand side is $0$. That's why I tried to circumvent that in my argument by choosing a slightly more complicated expression.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. I'm trying to figure out now how to actually use that "more complicated expression." I have $U(P_{0},f,\alpha) - L(P_{0},f,\alpha) \leq \frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))+2}(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)).$

Comment: Well, $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$ is just a number so we can just denote it by $y$. Then, you have:
$$\frac{\epsilon_0}{2y+2} y = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \cdot \frac{y}{y+1}$$

Can you find a nice upper bound for $\frac{y}{y+1}$? Can you conclude that $U(P_0,f,\alpha)-L(P_0,f,\alpha) \leq \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$? Can you use this to conclude that the left-hand side is strictly less than $\epsilon_0$?

Comment: Ah. Really neat. Thanks for the extensive help and the push.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of the sequence-Riemann criterion but holding the $ε-$dependence all over the proof.

Let an $ε>0$. There exists a $n=n(ε)\in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac {1}{n(ε)}<\frac{ε}{(b-a)^2}$. We set the uniform partition of $[a,b]$, $P_ε=\{a,a+\frac {b-a}{n(ε)}\,...,a+\frac {(n(ε)-1)(b-a)}{n(ε)},b\}$, so we get $U(f,P_ε)-L(f,P_ε)=\sum_{k=1}^{n(ε)}(a+\frac {k(b-a)}{n(ε)})\frac {b-a}{n(ε)}-\sum_{k=1}^{n(ε)}(a+\frac {(k-1)(b-a)}{n(ε)})\frac {b-a}{n(ε)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n(ε)}\frac {(b-a)^2}{n^2(ε)}=\frac {(b-a)^2}{n(ε)}<ε.$